# Questions about partial derivative notation in Evan's PDE book

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

In the appendix of Evan's PDE book, Evan writes

(1)$\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} = u_{x_i x_j}$.

But, this notation seems strange to me because $u_{x_i x_j}$ means that we differentiate $u$ with respect to $x_i$ and then with respect to $x_j$ while $\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$ means we differentiate $u$ with respect to $x_j$ and then with respect to $x_i$. Am I missing something?

(2)Given a multiindex $\alpha$, define

$D^\alpha u(x) := \dfrac{\partial^{|\alpha|}u(x)}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1}... \partial x_n^{\alpha_n}} = \partial x_1^{\alpha_1}...\partial x_n^{\alpha_n} u$

But, I have a question about this notation. It seems to me that this notation does not specify in which order the partial differentiation is performed.

For example, in $R^2$, if $\alpha = (2, 1)$, Evan's notation  $D^\alpha u(x) $ would mean $\partial x_1^2 \partial x_2^1 u$. But, what does $\partial x_1^2 \partial x_2^1 u$ mean? Does it mean that I differentiate u with resepct x2 once and then with respect to x1, and then with respect to x1? Or does it mean that I differentiate u with respect x1, and then with respect to x2, and then with respect to x1? Or does it mean that I differentiate u with respect x1, and then with respect to x1, and then with respect to x2?

There are three ways to get the multi index (2,1) and how do I know which one it is?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it does not specify any order. Indeed it is intended to be used with functions regular enough for Schwarz' theorem to apply. (For example, if $u$ has continuous partial derivatives up to order $|\alpha|$, the theorem applies)

Comment: You mind looking at my first question, which I forgot to include intiially? :)

Comment: Hi, I don't have Evans book with me, but again, it is probably the case that he is considering a $C^2$ function.

Comment: I see. nice profile picture btw :)